# Can I show only the rows in which a is smaller than b in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table and code which goes a little like this:

```
--code
SELECT numberA a, numberB B 
FROM numbers 
;

--table
a : B
2 : 5
3 : 1
2 : 3
```

But I only want to show the rows in which A < B and then show the increase in difference:

```
--table
a : B : diff
2 : 5 : 3
2 : 3 : 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the where condition:

```
SELECT numberA a, numberB B , numberB - numberA  AS diff
FROM numbers 
where numberA < numberB
;
```